# No space remained on ubuntu 18.04 running on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Windows 10, with installed memory RAM 8GB (7,89 GB usable). I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox on which I'm running ubuntu 18.04 with these settings:
[VM Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrBPk.png)

I was installing a python package and I got this:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device My virtual
```

**df -h** gives me:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.3G     0  3.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           679M  1.6M  678M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       9.8G  9.2G  129M  99% /
tmpfs           3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
/dev/loop0       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop2       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/495
/dev/loop4      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop6      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop7      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop8      4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
/dev/loop5      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop3       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop9       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop10      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop13     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop11      49M   49M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop14      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop12      94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
tmpfs           679M   28K  679M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           679M   20K  679M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0         74M   74M     0 100% /media/me/VBox_GAs_6.0.10
```

**sudo du -ks /*** gives me:

```
12484   /bin
115864  /boot
4   /cdrom
0   /dev
12432   /etc
3490348 /home
0   /initrd.img
0   /initrd.img.old
891320  /lib
4   /lib64
16  /lost+found
74971   /media
4   /mnt
20976   /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/2715/task/2715/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2715/task/2715/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2715/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2715/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
24  /root
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
1572    /run
11252   /sbin
2252020 /snap
4   /srv
483808  /swapfile
0   /sys
88  /tmp
2525472 /usr
1979916 /var
0   /VBox.log
0   /vmlinuz
0   /vmlinuz.old
```

**lsblk** gives me:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop1    7:1    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
loop2    7:2    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/495
loop3    7:3    0  54.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/1668
loop4    7:4    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
loop5    7:5    0 160.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop6    7:6    0   4.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/544
loop7    7:7    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/81
loop8    7:8    0   4.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/704
loop9    7:9    0  91.4M  1 loop /snap/core/8689
loop10   7:10   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/399
loop11   7:11   0  48.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
loop12   7:12   0  93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
loop13   7:13   0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/93
loop14   7:14   0  54.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
sda      8:0    0    10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    10G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  73.6M  0 rom  /media/me/VBox_GAs_6.0.10
```

Does this occur because I have limited storage on my machine or I misconfigured the storage when setting the virtual machine? 
To how much I should resize the VDI disk image givin my initial settings?

Thank you.

Comment: /dev/sda1 shows 99% full.  Looks like you started out with a 10GB drive?  You have two options.  Resize the VDI or make a new VDI, mount it, and move big stuff there.. the second one takes more Linux skills, the first one takes VM skills. :)  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I started with a 10GB. I didn't think of the second option, so thank you.